# Custom graph shape in Android

Tags: android

I am doing something like a quiz app. And in the end, I would like to show a percentage of the correct answers as the height of the fill of some shape with some colour. For example, I will have a shape of a tree, which I make as svg and if the user answers 100 % correct questions, the tree will be all green. If he answers 75 % correct, the tree will be green just up to the 75 % of is height.

Ideally, the fill would be a gradient - at the bottom red and then going through orange to green. Also, it would be nice if it would be possible to add some animation to the graph, so it could rise from the bottom up to the requested place.

I have found the answer to the gradient and animation, but only if it was just a bar chart. 
Even if anyone can answer just the shape part without the gradient and animation, I will be still happy.

Answer (score 0):

add an ImageView
then Programmatically set background svg with those colors

```
if(currentPercentage = 100){

//here to set background

}else if(currentPercentage = 70){

}else if(currentPercentage <= 33){

}else {

}
```

I suggest u to use different imageViews or whatever u want then  on required percentage(condition) visible those view...

```
if(currentPercentage = 100){


imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

imageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}else 
if(currentPercentage = 70){


imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

imageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}else 
if(currentPercentage <= 33){


imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}
```

Comment: That would be quite a difficult one as there can be a lot of questions. So, to graph to look realistic, I would have to cover at least every five percents, which would mean at least 20 images in total.

Comment: then set background images/color programaically in the imageview on required percentage

Comment: or u can use progressbar with your tree background and then set the progress

Comment: probably the progressBar is the best solution